# Indexing time field is not getting indexed in solr 6.1.0. giving error as undefined field: "event_timestamp"

Tags: java, apache, solr, solrj, solr4

I have run Apache solr 6.1.0. After that csv documents also gets indexed into solr 6.1.0 but while indexing timestamp field used for current indexing time of document is not getting indexed. Below is the structure of event time stamp field in schema.xml file.

```
<field name="event_timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" multiValued="false"/>
```

The above works for apache solr 4.10.1 but it is giving error in apache solr 6.1.0 as following,

```
o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field: "event_timestamp"
        at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getField(IndexSchema.java:1231)
        at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.getRangeQuery(SolrQueryPar
serBase.java:749)
        at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:398)
        at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:186)
        at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:107)
        at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:96)

        at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.parse(SolrQueryParserBase.
java:153)
        at org.apache.solr.search.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParser.java:50)
        at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:141)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryCompone
nt.java:208)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(Sea
rchHandler.java:267)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandl
erBase.java:156)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2036)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:657)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:464)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilte
r.java:257)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilte
r.java:208)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet
Handler.java:1668)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java
:581)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.j
ava:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.jav
a:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandl
er.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandl
er.java:1160)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:
511)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandle
r.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandle
r.java:1092)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.j
ava:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(Cont
extHandlerCollection.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerColl
ection.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper
.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.jav
a:244)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(Abstra
ctConnection.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoin
t.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceA
ndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(Exec
uteProduceConsume.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPoo
l.java:654)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool
.java:572)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me out of the problem. I am not getting what i am missing in new version of solr.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work. So I would focus on double-checking it is actually present in the active schema. Look in the Admin UI's Files screen and check that it is present in the file. Also, look in the schema field and see whether it is present in the drop-down.

If not, then you need to check your schema is in the correct location and the core has been reloaded to take care of it. Or, if you use SolrCloud, that the correct configuration has been uploaded into Zookeeper.

Comment: Thanks. My problem has been solved. It is with managed_schema file. "event_timestamp" field entry is missing in managed_schema file. Thank for your help.